# Is it that important to check socket connection manually?

Tags: c++, c, sockets

For example, let's consider IRC protocol; there is PING/PONG there to check if the client is still waiting. So while implementing my own IM simple protocol I came across such a question: do we really need nowadays do such checks? Can one rely on socket connection that much to not to check it manually? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What?? It's your design, it's up to you.  How can we possibly know the effect of a half-open connection on your overall requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it's your call. Your protocol, your code, you decide it. The answer is that you don't actually *need* it, but it's a neat feature. I can tell you, from personal experience, that it will avoid ghost connections and terminate them sooner in the event that a client leaves abruptly.

Of course that, eventually, half-open connections will end up being closed, but it can take some time. And I'm not talking about a few seconds - it really can take quite some minutes. This is frustrating and undesirable. I checked this by myself a few months ago when I was implementing an IRC server as part of a project for college (if you are interested: https://github.com/filipegoncalves/yaIRCd - it implements a very strict subset of the IRC protocol, and I haven't touched it for a while).

So, my advice would be go for it and use PING/PONG, but if that seems like a lot of work and you're just trying to get something to work, you can drop it without serious consequences - just keep in mind that you can have lots of ghost users that are not there anymore!

Answer (score 0):

If you *CAN* design an explicit ping/pong system into your custom protocol, you *SHOULD* do so (not all protocol models can faciliate it).

No, you cannot rely on the socket managing the connection for you.  Not all platforms support TCP keep-alives, for instance.  Or a socket can be partially closed halfway (ie, closed for reading but not for writing, or vice versa).  Or a connection can be lost abnormally without telling anyone, and it can take a long time (minutes, even hours) for the OS to detect a dead connection (this is primarily why keepalives and ping/pongs were created in the first place).  And so on.

So if you *CAN* be explicit about one party telling the other party that the connection is still alive and intentionally left open, please do so.  If a connection is idle for awhile, ping it.  If the pong times out, assume the connection is dead and close it.  And *IF* possible, design your protocol so either party can ping the other party at any time.  But *IF* that is not possible, at least try to let pings flow in one direction (client to server, or server to client) *IF* feasible.